# IIS blue-green deployment using ARR

Tags: ssl, iis, url-rewriting, arr

I am trying to figure out steps for deploying on IIS using ARR (Application Request Routing).
The setting was guided by this article https://kevinareed.com/2015/11/07/how-to-deploy-anything-in-iis-with-zero-downtime-on-a-single-server/
Based on the above article - everything works, but only when using http.
Only if we enable SSL (443 port) - everything stops working at once.
What was done:

1. Two sites, let's say devblue.somedomain.com and devgreen.somedomain.com, both use the following bindings 8001 and 443 and 8002 and 443
2. A farm has been brought up with the name let's say develop.somedomain.com
3. The above servers have been added to the develop.somedomain.com farm pool
4. Healthchecks are set up
5. Wildcard certificates added to IIS
6. Added entries to the HOSTS file for develop, devblue and devgreen, all pointing to 127.0.0.1
7. Set up an inbound URL Rewrite rule, to direct any requests for "develop" to the Server farm (This is one example of a global farm rule that I have used)

   ```
    <rule name="develop HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^443$" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^develop.somedomain.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="https://develop.somedomain.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
   ```

SSL off-loading checkbox unchecked.

I can request the blue and green sites individually. The health checks for the web farm seem to be working, so when I edit one from "down" to "up", it becomes healthy, and vice versa.

The problem is when requesting https://develop.somedomain.com - it is not routing to one of the servers in pool, so I suspect the problem is in the URL Rewrite rule (maybe I need more rules).

I've tried a lot of methods and different articles, connected sites to the farm on different https ports as well (8443 and 9443 for example), tried with and without offloading ssl.
Found some mentions to add HTTP_X_ARR_SSL but unfortunately I didn't get it right (should it be added to some rule or separately, I tried it both ways), but nothing works.

How do I figure out what is wrong? Can you please advise who had similar experience of configuration

Comment: `it is not routing to one of the servers in pool, so I suspect the problem is in the URL Rewrite rule`. Failed request tracing is more suitable for you to know what happened during url rewrite. Enable it at blue and green site and default website to check how ARR rewrite url. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've done it (Failed request tracing), but there is now any errors...

Comment: No error? If there's no error, FRT log will tell you what the request ARR received and what the rewritten url was and which backend server it forward request to.

Comment: @sssksv did you happen to find a solution? I have a similar issue. For me, the http request itself doesn't work. It throws a 404 not found. :-/

Comment: Finally I configured my blue-green deployment by switching between pre release and release site’s virtual directories